# integrate $\int \frac{dx}{4+3\sin2x}$

Tags: integration

> $$\int \frac{dx}{4+3\sin (2x)}$$

$u=2x$

$du=2dx$

$$\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{du}{4+3\sin(u)}$$

$v=\tan(\frac{u}{2})$

$du=\frac{2dv}{1+v^2}$

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{du}{4+3\sin(u)}={}&\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{\frac{2dv}{1+v^2}}{4+\frac{6v}{1+v^2}}=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{\frac{2dv}{1+v^2}}{\frac{4v^2+6v+4}{1+v^2}}={} \\
{}={}&\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{2dv}{4v^2+6v+4}=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{2dv}{4v^2+6v+4}={} \\
{}={}&\int \frac{2dv}{4v^2+6v+4}=\int \frac{dv}{4(v+\frac{3}{4})^2-1}
\end{align*}

$m=v+\frac{3}{4}$

$dm=dv$

\begin{align*}
\int \frac{dm}{4m^2-1}={}&4\int \frac{dm}{m^2-\frac{1}{4}}=4\int \frac{dm}{m^2-(\frac{1}{2})^2}={} \\
{}={}&\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{m-\frac{1}{2}}{m+\frac{1}{2}}\right)+C=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{v+\frac{3}{4}-\frac{1}{2}}{v+\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{2}}\right)+C={} \\
{}={}&\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{v-\frac{5}{4}}{v+\frac{11}{4}}\right)+C\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{v-\frac{5}{4}}{v+\frac{11}{4}}\right)+C={} \\
{}={}&\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{\tan(x)+\frac{5}{4}}{\tan(x)+\frac{11}{4}}\right)+C
\end{align*}

I think I got it wrong, but I cannot find the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{\frac{2dv}{1+v^2}}{4+\frac{6v}{1+v^2}}=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{\frac{2dv}{1+v^2}}{\frac{4v^2+6v+4}{1+v^2}}=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{2dv}{4v^2+6v+4}=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{2dv}{4v^2+6v+4}=\int \frac{2dv}{4v^2+6v+4}=\int \frac{dv}{4(v+\frac{3}{4})^2+\frac{7}{4}}$

Edit - You completed the square wrong. It should be $4(v+\frac{3}{4})^2+\frac{7}{4}$ not $4(v+\frac{3}{4})^2-1$

Comment: you are right, but that how can I continue?

Comment: @gbox it's a standard result from thereon.

Comment: Yes just continue with what you were doing and you should get a standard integral.

Comment: @Jack You have made an accidental switch at the end of your answer between the exact and the erroneous result.

Comment: It should be $4(v^2+\frac{3}{4})-5$

Comment: How did you obtain that?

Comment: $4v^2+6v+4=4(v^2+\frac{6}{4}v+1)$ now

$4((v+\frac{3}{4})^2))=4v^2+6v+9$ so we need to substract $-5$

Comment: No $4*\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2$ is not $9$